# Angular: Show value in a select

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two select and I show value if they exist:

**page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  customer: any = {
    city: '',
    state: '',
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    // I recover this info from BE
    this.customer.state = 'England';
    this.customer.city = 'London';
  }
}
```

page.html

```
  <div class="col configurator-form-input col-12 col-md-6">
  <label class="text">State *</label>
  <div
    class="input-group input-error"
    [ngClass]="
      customer.state ? 'input-group input error' : 'input-group input-error'
    "
  >
    <select
      id="state"
      class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="customer.state"
      [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
      (change)="onChangeProvinceForState($event.target.value)"
      appTab
      tabIndex="14"
    >
      <option disabled value="">Select State</option>
      <option
        *ngFor="let state of stateList"
        ngDefaultControl
        [value]="state.name"
      >
        {{ state.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col configurator-form-input">
  <label class="text">City *</label>
  {{ this.customer.city }}
  <div
    class="input-group input-error"
    [ngClass]="customer.city ? 'input-group' : 'input-group input-error'"
  >
    <!-- <span class="fake-option" *ngIf="existingCustomer">{{customer.city}}</span> -->
    <select
      id="city"
      name="city"
      class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="customer.city"
      [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
      appTab
      tabIndex="15"
    >
      <option value="">Select City</option>
      <option *ngFor="let city of citiesList" ngDefaultControl [value]="city">
        {{ city }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyendp?file=src/app/app.component.html

I recover the city and state from an api call, but I don't understand how to show in the select directly

EDIT:

```
onChangeStateForCity(e) {
        console.log("e ", e)
        let countiesObservable = this.citiesService.getAllState();
        countiesObservable.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.citiesList = data[e];
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the declaration of properties `stateList` and `citiesList`. I have modified your SB, to generate some static dropdown down options. You can easily assign these variables to the response you get from your API.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-453pf2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

app.component.ts (defined the variables):

```
stateList = [
    'England',
    'France'
  ]

  citiesList = [
    'London',
    'Paris'
  ]
```

app.component.html (bind them in template):

```
<option *ngFor="let state of stateList" ngDefaultControl [value]="state">
```

```
<option *ngFor="let city of citiesList" ngDefaultControl [value]="city">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I recover the cityList and stateList from a service, but if I have the value yet, why I can't show it?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, especially the part "but if I have the value yet, why I can't show it?". I see that you have modified your question to show how you are fetching `citiesList` from api. Have you checked how the response looks like? Is it a string array or list of objects? Can you update the question to show us how the data is?

Comment: The value will be shown if the value is available in the options list.

Comment: You need to show us how the data is coming from your API. If data types are not correctly matching, it won't appear in options list.

Comment: Ok I have understand what you means, thank you for help!

Comment: FYI, you are also calling states api to assign list of cities, not sure if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Just add array of `stateList` and `citiesList`.

```
stateList = [{ name: 'England' }];
citiesList = ['London'];
```